# Player does not die to specific thing which it should die to (2d platformer)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"){
      transform.position = new Vector3(-9.5f, -4f, 0f)};`
```

In this program whenever the player touches an object called "enemy" it is supposed to "die", before removing the semi-colon, it "died" to anything it touched, now I removed it dies to nothing. Anyone know how to to make it die to only "enemy".

Comment: Remove the `;` after the `if`

Comment: The Guy, the Man, the Legend. Quick and simple.

Comment: Do not edit your post in a way that invalidates answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this piece of code where it says

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
```

it gathers the tag of the object, not the name which I was supposed to look for, so in order to fix it, the code should look for the name which can be done by using

`if (col.gameObject.name == "Enemy")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No idea to be honest but you do have a syntactical error:

if (something) ; { do stuff }

See the semicolon between your if and your code block? That basically breaks your if statement so it always ends up running your code block.

Comment: While correct, errors like this are the kind that has a close reason. You should flag to close (typographic error) in the future.